# Which is better: to get sound from the amplifier with a microphone or to use the REC OUT jack (if it is installed on the amplifier)?

Tags: audio-recording, mixer, amplifier, guitar

My amp has a REC OUT connector for 1/4 jack. I need to output the sound from the amplifier to the mixer. What is better in my case - use a microphone for this or connect using REC OUT? What are the pros/cons?

Comment: Is this for a live concert or recording a song?

Comment: @ToddWilcox for a live concert

Answer (score 2):

It depends as it is a question of taste.

For an electrical guitar the amplifier is often seen as part of the instrument. The sound you want to amplify very often is the sound coming out of the speaker. Typically we tend to use a SM57 pointing halfway between the rim and center of the speaker element.

If you use the REC out you will get a cleaner signal. You might preferr it, or not. Typically we always use a transformer DI box for these outputs to get isolation from ground loops. (Ground loops typically comes around as mains hum at double mains frequency, in Europe 100Hz).

On stage we like to have small wattage amplifiers giving the sound mixer a reasonable chance to balance sound (guitarists tend to set volume at 11). I love 5W guitar amps, hate 100W on smaller stages. Even better is no stage amplifiers at all where the musicians use in-ear monitoring. There are plenty of "amp simulation" boxes around allowing this to happen. Give the drummer e-drums while you are at it.

Comment: > Typically we always use a transformer DI box for these outputs to get isolation from ground loops. (Ground loops typically comes around as mains hum at double mains frequency, in Europe 100Hz).   Can you please elaborate on this without going into the details of electrical engineering? In simple words. And what happens if you don't use the DI box in this case?

Comment: First: it may work without a DI-box with no problems. But what can happen is that the mixer is grounded and the amplifier is grounded. As both grounds meet somewhere this in effect creates a really large pickup coil inducing mains hum in the signal. Additionally, in large venues (as you ask, I don´t believe this is the case here), the ground potential may be different enough between stage and front of house mixer to induce problems in electronic circuits. By the way, DO NOT ISOLATE the ground on the amplifier, it can potentially be lethal (I've seen guitarists do this on their tube amplifiers)

Comment: @John: it is worth having a simple transformer DI-box along in the kit. When needed it solves a difficult problem for very little money. Not clear where you live, but you should be able to find a simple  for 30USD or 30EUR from mailorder (shops tend to charge more). I recommend a "passive" DI (NOT an "active") for most use cases. Example is here (not a recommendation): https://www.thomann.de/intl/millenium_die_dibox_passiv.htm?shp=eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiZGUiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6MiwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOjJ9&reload=1